# Approach for forecasting time-series with several time-series of different frequency

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

The time-series I'm looking to forecast consists of daily data.

The other time-series are made up of each of daily, weekly and monthly levels.

Top of mind approach is to use an MV regression, obviously made more complicated here by the mixed frequency. Have seen MIDAS approaches, and reverse MIDAS in my case, for dealing with this. Am otherwise aware of SARIMA approaches, though I don't expect AR/MA effects to be primary drivers.

My ideal would be to 'filter' the impact of lower frequency variables (ie, monthly TS) and use the higher frequency independent variables (perhaps even 'filtering' a 2nd time for weekly vars) to model my dependent variable. This ideally allow a more precise forecast for my dependent daily variable.

Can also think of this as removing longer term trends from my dependent TS and attempting to model ~daily movements with my daily indep variables.

Comment: Could you tell us what your research question is ?

Comment: @CaroZ, how to approach time-series forecasting for X and Y and multiple frequencies